# How add a listview inside a viewpager in android

Tags: android-layout

I've been trying to get a list view that can be swipe to change the its items to show the following or preceding week details. Here is what my layout file looks like
'

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home_pannels_pager">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/week_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

But I didn't get what i want. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how ViewPager works. You feed the pages to [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) with a [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html). Your ListView will be contained within a Fragment created by the PagerAdapter.

In the layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home_pannels_pager" />
```

In the FragmentActivity with this layout:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Example of simle PagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public FrontPageAdapter(FragmentManager Fm) {
        super(Fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt("position", position);
        FragmentPage fragment = new FragmentPage();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // return count of pages
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Example of FragmentPage:

```
public class FragmentPage extends Fragment {

    public FragmentPage() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frontpage, container, false);  
        // probably cast to ViewGroup and find your ListView          

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        int position = b.getInt("position");

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer to give you very brief structure.

Comment: Well, That Helped me a lot.. ;-)